# Data not available in GridView ItemTemplate field onPreRender

Tags: asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

I have this scenario.

An ascx contains this GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dataTable" runat="server" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Key">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)(Container.DataItem)).Key%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)(Container.DataItem)).Value%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I'm loading a fake Array into the GridView during the Page_Load

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
values.Add("test1", "2");
values.Add("test2", "2");

dataTable.DataSource = values;
dataTable.DataBind();
```

If during the OnPreRender I try to check the value of

```
dataTable.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text
```

It has no value. Then the grid is rendered perfectly and every value is in place.
Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a label control like this:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Key"> 
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%# ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)(Container.DataItem)).Key%>"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

And then access the value like this on the user control´s PreRender:

```
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = dataTable.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[1] as Label;
        string t = lbl.Text;
    }
```

Or like this on the consumer page´s PreRender:

```
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView dataTable = dataTableWebUserControl1.FindControl("dataTable") as GridView;
        Label lbl = dataTable.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[1] as Label;
        string t = lbl.Text;
    }
```

Comment: I tested this code in visual studio and worked for me... you mention the PreRender event handler as OnPreRender, the actual event handler that is automatically wired up is Page_PreRender, that could be the problem

Comment: And you're completely right, of course. The problem is that I was reading the cell Text property, but now it's rendered by the Label/Literal, so that is the control to check.
Thank you for your help! :)